# Make interprets compiler options as shell command

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, tiny-core-linux

I'm trying to compile fbsplash under Tiny Core Linux using autotools. In the middle of compilation it crashed saying "LD: attempted static link to dynamic object /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so"
I've got rid of that, commenting out option "-all-static" in the Makefile. Now it crashes after

```
/bin/bash: O2: not found
/bin/bash: w: not found
/bin/bash: DTARGET_KERNEL: not found
```

All of these options have dashes before them. It looks like:

```
fbcondecor_helper_CFLAGS = -O2 -w \...
fbcondecor_helper_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) -DTARGET_KERNEL
```

But somehow my shell interprets them as commands without dashes.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First, you are not using the autotools.  You are using a configure script that was generated using the autotools.  (If indeed you are running autoconf, or autoreconf, that is a different issue and there is (much) more room for error on your part.)  In either case, you should never hand edit the generated Makefile.  (So short answer to "What's wrong?" is, "you edited the Makefile".)  Instead, add `--disable-static` when you run `configure`.

Comment: I know little of autotools; I've got used to ./configure && make. In this case, I'm doing autoreconf -fiv && automake && ./configure && make. There aren't some configuration files, so autoconf doesn't work, and I have to do autoreconf -fiv (I have read this solution in the Internet).

Comment: I've tried also to configure using --disable-static option, it won't help; it went on trying to static link /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so and giving the same errors... Then I tried to configure with --disable-shared to prevent it using shared libraries from /usr/local/lib, there are static libs in the subdirectory, but it doesn't use it for some reason.

Comment: Btw, when I run 'make' the first time in the source-root directory, it starts compiling libs/libjpeg/ and complains of "make [3]: O2: command not found" (x10 times). Then I go into libs/libjpeg and run 'make' from there; it compiles well. After that I return to the ../../ and restart make, it counts libjpeg as made and starts making zlib and crashes with same errors. So I must go to libs/zlib/ and run make there and repeat this process until all libraries in libs/ subdirectories are built "autonomously".

Comment: Grrr.  Projects should not require their users to run autoreconf, but that won't address your problem.   You can try passing flags to the linker to tell it to look in the local directory before looking in /usr/local/lib.  Perhaps `./configure --disable-shared LDFLAGS=-L$(pwd)/libs`

Comment: My posts lack much relevant information, it is hard to answer them correctly without viewing all the scene, I'm sure.( I've tried this flag option it didn't help; it's an old project last updated in 2011, I don't know if it's correct for newest versions of autotools. Autoconf complains of some undefined... damn... I'm under a different OS, can't give an exact quotation... Some undefined constants e.g. AM_INIT_LIBTOOL, or AM_CONDITIONAL. Only after that I do autoreconf -- it creates a working configure.

Comment: I could 'capture' all the process from the beginning to the end in text, but I'm afraid it would be too long for a comment or even to a post...